# import psycopg2 Not working in Kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes, flask, psycopg2

So currently I am trying to learn Kubernetes. I created a Flask app where I used an import -import psycopg2.

Then I used `pip3 freeze > requirements.txt`   to add all dependency to file.I had few weird dependency like `altgraph @ file:///AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9dd5efe2-7fad-11ee-b588-aa530c46a9ea/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/python3/altgraph-0.17.2-py2.py3-none-any` but I though these are irrelevant for me so I removed this and 3 more which were - future , macho lib and six ( all these in same @ file ... path )

I created a Dockerfile which has this content

```
FROM python:3.13-rc-slim-bullseye

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests \
  build-essential default-libmysqlclient-dev \
  && pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip \
  && apt-get install -y libpq-dev \
  && pip install psycopg2

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./requirements.txt /app
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --requirement /app/requirements.txt
COPY . /app

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["python3", "server.py"]
```

and my requirements.txt file has this content

```
blinker==1.7.0
click==8.1.7
Flask==3.0.0
importlib-metadata==7.0.1
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
psycopg2-binary==2.9.9
PyJWT==2.8.0
python-dotenv==1.0.0
Werkzeug==3.0.1
zipp==3.17.0
```

Now did docker build . and then pushed it to docker and I could see the commit in docker hub.

After that I created yaml files inside a kubernetes folder.Started minikube and ran `kubectl apply -f .` and checked the pods using `kubectl get pods`. I saw status as  `CrashLoopBackOff`  when I debugged using `kubectl logs \<pod-name\> -c \<container-name\>` and got this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/server.py", line 3, in <module>
    import psycopg2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.13/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-313-aarch64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _PyInterpreterState_Get
```

Not able to understand what the problem is here. in my local I am able to start flask Server and it doesn't say import issue.

I have tried adding psycopg2-binary in my requirements.txt instead of psycopg2 and also tried to add a direct pip install psycopg2 command in Dockerfile.I also read that `When you install psycopg2 or psycopg2-binary using pip within the Docker container, it will require libpq-dev to build and function properly.` so I added the install in docker file itself -`apt-get install -y libpq-dev` . Still same issue. Any clue what's wrong and where should I start looking?

Comment: try install `gcc` in line `apt-get -y install libpq-dev gcc`

Comment: Still the same issue.

Comment: I see you use python 3.13 . Can you downgrade to python:3.11-rc-slim-bullseye or 12? . I looked in psycopg pypi url only to python 12 https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/